C - strtok skips the second token
I am working on a firewall application in C. The application takes an IP as part of an input. The IP can be standalone or a range, like this:
Standalone: x.x.x.x
Range: x.x.x.x-x.x.x.x
where x is an integer between 0 and 255 (inclusive)
For the ranged IP, I am using strtok(ip, "-") to first parse the two IPs, then call the function splitOnDot to parse the ip using "." as the delimiter, converting the string tokens to integers and ensuring the int is in the range 0-255.
However, calling splitOnDot causes strtok(NULL,"-"); to return null, not the second ip in the range. Can someone see my error?
---CODE---
//Recieves a string with no '-', attempts to split by '.', convert string to integer and validate integers
int splitOnDot(char* ipStr){
    
    char *ipTokens = strtok(ipStr, ".");

    int xxxCount = 0;

    while(ipTokens){
    
        char *endptr;
        long int xxxIp;

        xxxIp = strtol(ipTokens, &endptr, 10);

        if(endptr == ipStr){
            return 0; 
        }
        else if (*endptr != '\0'){
            return 0; 
        }
        else{
            if(xxxIp >= 0 && xxxIp <= 255){
                xxxCount += 1;
            } 
            else{
                return 0;
            }
        } 

        ipTokens = strtok(NULL,".");
    }

    if(xxxCount == 4){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}


//Recieves a string in the form 'x.x.x.x-x.x.x.x', splits the 2 IP's by "-", and validates the IP
int splitOnDash(char* ipStr){

    char *fullIp = strtok(ipStr, "-");
    char fullIpCopy [] = "tempString";

    while(fullIp){
    
        strcpy(fullIpCopy, fullIp);
        int validIp = splitOnDot(fullIpCopy);

        if(validIp == 0){
            return 0;
        } 

        fullIp = strtok(NULL,"-");
    } 
    
    return 1; 
}


Why do you expect the second call to strtok() to return something other than NULL? Presumably there is only one - to detect, which gets consumed by the first call to strtok().

There are a number of Q&A which this is a duplicate of.

Have you considered using something like inet_aton to properly parse the input?

The strtok function uses static data to keep track of what it's parsed so far.  If you attempt to use it to do multiple "levels" of delimiters like this, the parsing at one level will interfere with the parsing at another level.
For this, you instead want to use strtok_r.  This function takes an additional argument to keep track of its state.
So splitOnDash would be modified as follows:
int splitOnDash(char* ipStr){

    char *saveptr = NULL;   // state for strtok_r
    char *fullIp = strtok_r(ipStr, "-", &saveptr);
    char fullIpCopy [] = "tempString";

    while(fullIp){
    
        strcpy(fullIpCopy, fullIp);
        int validIp = splitOnDot(fullIpCopy);

        if(validIp == 0){
            return 0;
        } 

        fullIp = strtok_r(NULL,"-", &saveptr);
    } 
    
    return 1; 
}

And similarly for splitOnDot.
If you're working on Windows, the function you want is called strtok_s.

If you have the number in format 'x.x.x.x-x.x.x.x' then you can simply
int ips[8];
if(sscanf(ipStr, "%d.%d.%d.%d-%d.%d.%d.%d", ips + 0, ips + 1, ips + 2, ips + 3, ips + 4, ips + 5, ips + 6, ips + 7) != 8) return 0;
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(ips)/sizeof(ips[0]); i++)
  if(ips[i] < 0 || ips[i] > 255) return 0;l
return 1;


I'd think parsing to an array of unsigned char using %hhu for each format placeholder would get the checks you want for free (that is, an out of range value would cause sscanf to fail early and return a value other than 8, removing the need for a loop to check for out-of-range values, since they can't happen, and making the code simpler). Or if you want to be absolutely sure you're not on a weirdo system, use SCNu8 and uint8_t I guess? Your solution will handle the weirdo system, but it's such a weirdo system I'd simply ensure the code won't work on it and fix if needed.

@ShadowRanger the standard does not justify your claim.

Yes. strtok is not reentrant. Both your splitOn... use strtok. So splitOnDot destroyed the internal state of strtok that splitOnDash was counting on.
Use strtok_r instead.
